AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OAuth1UserHandler'
This is some python code that gets this error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OAuth1UserHandler'
import tweepy as tw
auth = tw.OAuth1UserHandler(my_api_key, my_api_secret,my_api_access_token,my_api_other_token)

Can't get pass this point.

What version of tweepy are you using?
tweepy document
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
)

Above tweepy API is v1.1
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)

This API is v2
I guess you're using different version of tweepy API.
Check version of the module.
Thanks.

tweepy (3.10.0)

python getfollowers.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "getfollowers.py", line 14, in 
auth = tw.Client(my_api_key, my_api_secret,my_api_access_token,my_api_other_token)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no

Can you share me whole getfollowers.py code?

Trying to find out how I can share it

Just edit your post and paste the code with code blocks wrapping it.
